# Query for fetching address in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table of users, and in this table I have 2 columns id and username and another table useraddress which has id, userid(foreign key for the id in user table)and address. How can I write a SQL query to get the addresses of the users along with userid and also the query to fetch the unique addresses for each id

I used query this which gives me below result but I want count of addresses a user has and also want to display unique address corresponding each user.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you looked into JOIN s?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) I.e. [mcve].

Comment: hi @Brad yes i tried this  select UserName,Address from UserName join Users on UserName.UserID=Users.UserID but for a user let's say there are 3 address this query displays all and i also need to have COUNT of each address alongwith the unique address

Comment: @RyanWilson SQL server

Comment: If a user has multiple addresses to count, then how could output show a unique address? Need to show raw data sample and desired result as text tables, not image. SQL statement should be text, not image.

Comment: @RavneetKaur So you want to count how many unique addresses are associated with a given user and also display each unique address? And do you expect all this data in one row per user?

Comment: @RyanWilson yes but differnt queries might be there for count and for unique addresses associated with a given user

Comment: @RavneetKaur Does each address need to be in its own column or could you place them all in one column separated by some delimiter?

Comment: Show sample data as already requested. The output you show does not make sense and there is no count attempted.

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
select id, username
from users
where exists (
    select distinct userid, useraddress
    from useraddress
    where useraddress.userid = users.id
)

select id, userid, useraddress
from useraddress
where exists (
    select distinct id, username
    from users where users.id = useraddress.userid
)
```

[example image with results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOrqM.png)

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

1. Query to get the addresses of the users along with userid and username.

   ```
   SELECT u.id,u.username,ua.address
   FROM   users u
   JOIN useraddress ua ON u.id = ua.userid;
   ```
2. Query to get the count of addresses for each userid.

   ```
   SELECT u.id, Count(ua.address)
   FROM   users u
   JOIN useraddress ua ON u.id = ua.userid
   GROUP  BY ua.userid;
   ```
3. Query to fetch the unique addresses for each id.

   ```
   SELECT distinct ua.address, u. id
   FROM useraddress ua 
   JOIN  users u on ua.userid = u. id;
   ```